# Convert group by json array documents into single json document

Tags: json, mongodb, algorithm, spring-data

Team,

I am working with mongodb along with spring data.

I got some results from mongodb through aggregation (group). Now I want to convert multi line group by json array into single json document like below

FROM:

```
{ "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100106" }
{ "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100107" }
{ "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "2", "TIME" : "16100108" }
{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100106" }
{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100107" }
{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "2", "TIME" : "16100108" }
```

TO:

```
{
   "ABC" : {                       //SERVICE
            1: {                   //BUCKET
                16100106 : 8,      //TIME:count
                16100107 : 8
            },
            2: {
                16100108 : 8
            },
         },
   "XYZ" : {
            1: {
                16100106 : 10,
                16100107 : 10
            },
            2: {
                16100108 : 10
            },
         }

}
```

**Complexities**:

1. Number of columns will change (addition of new columns in the $groupby/$project)
2. Should be able to pass the order, the current example shows the order like

   `SERVICE --> BUCKET --> TIME --> count`,

   but this should be changeable like

   `TIME --> BUCKET --> SERVICE --> count`

Hence looking for any generic library supporting this already? OR any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the newer to use Stack Overflow, I'm glad to contribute my idea to get an anwser.

I don't know how it works with mongodb, but if you use node.js, you can extend a function with Array, like this

```
Array.prototype.converGroupToSingle = function(){
    var r = {}
    this.forEach(function(s){
         //not have SERVICE
        ;(r[s.SERVICE] || (r[s.SERVICE] = {[s.BUCKET]:{[s.TIME]:s.count}},false))
        //have SERIVCE
        && (
            // not have BUCKET
            (r[s.SERVICE][s.BUCKET] || (r[s.SERVICE][s.BUCKET] = {[s.TIME]:s.count},false))
            //have BUKCET but not have TIME
            && (r[s.SERVICE][s.BUCKET][s.TIME] || (r[s.SERVICE][s.BUCKET][s.TIME] = s.count,false))
        )
    })
    return r
}
```

And use it, like this

```
var arrGroup = [
    { "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100106" }
    ,{ "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100107" }
    ,{ "count" : 8,  "SERVICE" : "ABC", "BUCKET" : "2", "TIME" : "16100108" }
    ,{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100106" }
    ,{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "1", "TIME" : "16100107" }
    ,{ "count" : 10, "SERVICE" : "XYZ", "BUCKET" : "2", "TIME" : "16100108" }
]

var singleGroup = arrGroup.converGroupToSingle()
```

if you output the `singleGroup`, it like this

```
// the singleGroup
{
ABC:
    {
        '1': { '16100106': 8, '16100107': 8 },
        '2': { '16100108': 8 }
    },
XYZ:
    {
        '1': { '16100106': 10, '16100107': 10 },
        '2': { '16100108': 10 }
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Thanks.